# Magento 2 - Observer after order not work

Tags: magento2, orders, event-observer

In Magento 2, I try to add an observer `sales_order_place_after` and it doesn't work.

`app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/event.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_order_place_after">
        <observer name="vendor_module_order_place_after" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\OrderPlaceAfter" />
    </event>
</config>
```

`app/code/Vendor/Module/Observer/OrderPlaceAfter.php`

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

class OrderPlaceAfter implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_logger;
    protected $_myObserverFactory;

    /**
    * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $_logger
    */

    public function __construct(
        \Vendor\Module\Logger\Logger $logger,
        \Vendor\Module\Model\MyObserverFactory $myObserverFactory
    ) {
        $this->_logger = $logger;
        $this->_myObserverFactory = $myObserverFactory;
        $this->_logger->info('test');
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $this->_logger->info('START - Observer Order');
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();

        $this->_logger->info($order->getData());
        $this->_logger->debug($order->getData());

        var_dump($order->getData());die;
        $this->_logger->info('END - Observer Order');
    }
}
```

After placing an order no logs are saved and var_dump; die; do not show.

Can you help me please ?

Comment: Clear cache and then check it.

Comment: @Black Not require.

Comment: @DhadukMitesh I run every command, cache:clean / flush / upgrade / deploy but it's not better...

Comment: See my answer...

Comment: @Fabien, did you try my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your event file name with `events.xml`

`app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/events.xml`

Clear cache and check it.

Comment: Thank you that was the problem!

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare your observer in the appropriate scope. Also make sure that it is named **events.xml**.

**Frontend:**

Put your **events.xml** to `<module-dir>/etc/frontend/events.xml` since this is a frontend event.

**Backend:**

For backend events put it in `<module-dir>/etc/adminhtml/events.xml`

[Documentation](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/ext-best-practices/extension-coding/observers-bp.html)

Comment: Thanks but that didn't solve the problem